Firefox signs out Google after closing all tabs or reboot (Ubuntu 24.04 LTS; GNOME Shell 46.0)
If I reboot the system, Firefox asks me to sign in to Google again. Current settings:

Privacy and Security > Firefox will 'Remember history'
Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed [DISABLED]

How to fix this issue?
Obs.: It does not happen with my Notion account, for example. Only Google.

Output to which firefox:
/usr/bin/firefox


Output to ls -l /usr/bin/firefox:
rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2377 Nov  6  2022 /usr/bin/firefox


Firefox came with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS


Welcome to AskUbuntu! Can you mention your Firefox version and the output of which firefox command in your question??

Your first comment also belongs in the question as info not as a comment. Comments do not always stay around and many people only read the question not the comments.

which firefox -> /usr/bin/firefox

In a lot of instances, /usr/bin/firefox is a symbolic link.  Please give more information about which firefox.   1) result of ls -l /usr/bin/firefox    and 2) which firefox (SNAP, flatpak, traditionally installed, 'the one that came with [X,L,K]Ubuntu ie.flavor of ubuntu or 'manually installed from the mozilla tar ball.



Output to 'ls -l /usr/bin/firefox': rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2377 Nov  6  2022 /usr/bin/firefox


Firefox came with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS



@Hélio Nogueira Cardoso - Great that you have included the fact you are using the standard firefox that comes with Ubuntu 24.04.  Personally I don't experience what you describe because I do not usually sign into google except on vary rare occasions and then I would totally clear the browser after that. It's not wrong what you are doing - just not what I do

Not an Ubuntu issue. A FF issue.  You could try purge FF, and install the flatpak FF.
